# Offset text in TextView

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="90px"
    android:layout_height="20px">
    <TextView
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_600"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="hello this is some long text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code successfully vertically aligns the text in the text view. The font's size is 75% of the height of the view.

[image]

However, if I increase the size of the text to, say, 19px or 95% of the height of the view, the vertical centering breaks because it seems that the text view won't draw the text any higher than the top of the view.

[image]

Is it possible to shunt the text up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drew the background separately using `Canvas.DrawLine` and moved the `TextView` up by 10% of the height of the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height to `wrap_content` then use `lineSpacingMultiplier` to set the line height to be `1.3` times higher than the text height.  This will mean that the text is always approximately 75% of the line height.

Additionally you should use `sp` instead of `dp` for text sizes so that when people change the size of text in their settings the size of text in your app updates, this is important for accessibility.

Finally you don't need to wrap your `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` unless you plan to add more views

Comment: I'm using px not dp and the value is based on a runtime height. Will that avoid problems with different text/screen sizes?

Comment: It will cause different problems, in a high density screen your text will be tiny compared to a low density screen if you use `px`.  Generally `px` should be avoided for sizes on android because of the screen size and density issues

Comment: But given a box of x pixels that's provided by a 3rd party control, to base the height of some text as a percentage of x will be safe? (As long as the 3rd party control is scaling properly...)

Comment: If the third party is providing the height of the text view then you'll have to set the height of your text programmatically since you won't know the height at compile time for xml.  In that case px may be fine, but the third party will probably cause your view to look strange on certain devices.  I would recommend not using that third party if possible

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the text size at runtime.

Comment: Then you'll have to set a viewtreeobserver and wait until the textview is laid out, get the height and set the text size to be 75% of that value.

Comment: I'm not finding line multiplier to have an effect on the where the first line of text is drawn. From the reference, it says, "Extra spacing between lines of text, as a multiplier." I want an upward offset, not extra spacing below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178868/discussion-between-zachary-sweigart-and-ian-warburton).

Comment: Thanks but I found a rejig.